How can I make separate .d.ts type definitions in package.json?
There are some things that are in the browser package but not in the node package. Therefore, I need to define separate types for both. But I couldn't find a way, is that possible?
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/index.cjs",
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
        }
    }


This is works for me:
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": {
                "default": "./dist/index.es.js",
                "types": "./dist/browser/index.d.ts"
            },
            "require": {
                "default": "./dist/index.cjs",
                "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
            }
        }
    }

